# Несовместимость array на хостинге

Tags: php

Имеется код php:

```
$price = [
    "main" => "100",
    "t2" => "100"
];
```

На `localhost` данный код работает,а на хостинге выдает ошыбку:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '['

Как устранить проблему ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создание массива через `[]` доступно только с версии php 5.4

У вас на хостинге старая версия php стоит. Создавайте по старинке через `array()`.

Comment: К большому сожалению проблема действительно оказалась в этом. Спасибо.

Comment: @ИгорьСавинов да не за что. Если ответ вам помог, отметьте его как принятый.

Comment: @ИгорьСавинов сейчас на хостингах в большинстве случаев можно выбрать версию больше чем 5.3. Посмотрите в настройках. у 90% хостеров можно выбрать уже и 5.4 и 5.5